# systemtray icon from eclipse's SWT not visible

Tags: 14.04, unity, java, system-tray

I try to add an icon to systemtray using eclipse's SWT, however I can't make it visible. What could be a problem?

I googled some posts telling to whitelist `'all'` using`dconf-editor`
so I added 'all' to 
`com->canonical->desktop->unity-gtk-module->whitelist` with no success...

Any suggestions?